# a value of type "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int [0]"

Tags: c++, class, oop

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
    public:
    int data1 = 0;
    int data2 = 0;
    int data3 = 0;

    void setData(int d1, int d2, int d3)
    {
        data1 = d1;
        data2 = d2;
        data3 = d3;
    }

    int data[3]; 
    data[0] = data1;
    data[1] = data2;
    data[2] = data3;
};
```

In VsCode there are highlighted error messages on data[0], data[1] and data[2] --> "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

and in the same line, where I initialised data[0] = data1, there is error message --> "a value of type "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int [0]" "

what is the meaning of these errors.

Comment: In the first case the assignments are part of a function. In the second case they are outside of any function, and that is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that you are assigning values to `data[0]`, `data[1]` and `data[2]` directly inside class definition instead of doing the assignments inside a **member function**.

You can **solve** this by **replacing** `int data[3];` with:

```
int data[3]{data1, data2, data3};
```

Also, **remove** the following three statments:

```
//remove these three statements 
 data[0] = data1;
 data[1] = data2;
 data[2] = data3;
```

##### Modified Code

So the modified code looks like below:

```
class student
{
    public:
    int data1 = 0;
    int data2 = 0;
    int data3 = 0;

    void setData(int d1, int d2, int d3)
    {
        data1 = d1;
        data2 = d2;
        data3 = d3;
    }

    int data[3]{data1, data2, data3}; //initializing data
   
};
```

Comment: As given, there's no reason to use the member variables.  `int data[3]{0, 0, 0};` would have a same effect.  If an explicit constructor was provided, then referring to the other member variables may make sense (but I'd still consider it a code smell in a code review).

Comment: @Eljay I agree but still OP wants to know why the error occurs and how to solve it. I just provided one possible way of solving it. There are other ways as you already mentioned. Also, this is not a code review. Though your comment might help OP for future purposes(programs).